# Data replication between two web nodes

Tags: nginx, replication

I have Wordpress installation running on two web servers (Nginx). There is unidirectional synchronization from server A to server B and I'm using `lsyncd` for this purpose.

- with his configuration I have to add blog posts from the first web server so the data is replicated to the second one - how I can force access to Wordpress back-end only from the first web server?

Please note that both servers have the same domain for Wordpress.

Regards

Comment: Is there a load balancer in front of the two servers, or are they contactable directly?

Comment: Unfortunately only RRDNS

Comment: have you got 2 separate DB's on both boxes?

Comment: I've got Master/Slave configuration on separate servers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how I can force access to Wordpress back-end only from the first web
>   server?

It **could** be achieved with a two-step process...

Step 1:

On your *second* web server, please add the following blocks just before `location /` block...

```
location /wp-login.php {
  return 301 $scheme://ip.of.1st.server$request_uri;
}

location /wp-admin {
  return 301 $scheme://ip.of.1st.server$request_uri;
}
```

Step 2:

On your *first* web server, please add the following vhost configuration...

```
server {
    server_name ip.of.1st.server;
    return 301 $scheme://domainname.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Sign the backend link with backend-d9c4efd247b4cf75ad6c0fc5-xx.xx.xx.xx.dns-x.wordpress.com and use it against commercial and government intelligence.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using a L7 load balancer, you could just redirect based on URI. If you are using RRDNS - then you don't really have much control.

But you could just use a shared file-system like NFS, then it wouldn't matter which machine was running the admin - as it would essentially be bidirectional.

Comment: There is only RRDNS. Unfortunately I have to stick to the current setup for now (two separate web nodes without shared storage) so is there any better solution for data replication than "lsyncd" that is bidirectional?

Comment: If the replication needs to be in real-time, `lsyncd` is the next best approach (other than NFS/Gluster). If it can be slightly delayed, the `rysnc` on a cron would would and could operate from each machine. What's the point in 2 servers using RRDNS - you don't have proper load balancing or any proper redundancy?

Comment: I'm using dyndns traffic management but I'm planning to use Red Hat Load balancer in the future. I think shared storage would be the best option.

Answer (score 1):

You could use domain like backend-d9c4efd247b4cf75ad6c0fc5-xx.xx.xx.xx.dns-x.wordpress.com and you would have to use different database schema and eventually sql replication between users too. You can even do more security and copy sensitive banking data only to your backend and not the frontend.

Comment: My initial idea was to create rewrite rule on the web servers as follow:

http://example.com/wp-admin/ to admin.example.com on both web servers (with admin.example.com pointing to the first one) - however the problem is that WordPress can be access it only with the main domain (example.com) and there's no way to login to the WordPress admin on each server, since they're set by domain from the database.

Comment: What about slightly patching  the code, so it works from both? This would be the best solution from security view, so when you access backend, you dont access the same account as on the frotend. This way, you can secure filesystem on the frontend.

Answer (score 1):

Can you exclude files from replicating with lsyncd?  You could just remove some of the files from /wp-admin/ on the 2nd host so you can't use that host to create posts, like admin.php.

Note: **Untested**.

Comment: WordPress can be access it only with one domain so there won't be a way to redirect clients to the admin back-end on the first node.